# How to remove an extra comma in dictionary of tuples in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary of tuple values some with 1-element tuples and some with multiple element tuples and I want to pass each tuple from the dictionary to an Oracle SQL query and perform some operation. But, unfortunately, 1-element tuples generate an additional comma at the end just to differentiate between a list and a tuple in python which is annoying.

My dictionary of tuples looks like below:

```
orderid_dict = 

`{foo : (121, 122, 123, 124),
  bar : (221,),
  zoo : (331, 332), 
  xyz : (441,442,443, 444, 445,446),
  abc : (551,)}`

`
dfs=[]
for x in orderid_dict:
     query =  """select  * from table where order_id in 
      """+str(orderid_dict[x])
 df=pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
dfs.append(df)`
```

While I execute this loop, it throws an error saying:

**DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select  * from table where order_id in (221,)':ORA-00936: missing expression**

Is there a way I can strip of the last comma for all the 1-element tuples in the dictionary?

I tried using:

```
`for x in orderid_dict:
     ",".join(str(x) for x in orderid_dict[x])`
```

and it doesn't give me an error and it doesn't work.

I'd really appreciate if some can help me with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly advice to not try to paste input-fragments directly into the SQL-string. Instead, use late binding:

```
inputs = (1,2,3,)
sql = """SELECT *
         FROM table
         WHERE order_id IN (%s)
      """ % (",".join(["?"]*len(inputs)), )
pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, params=inputs)
```

What's happening here is that the SQL-string is expanded to `... IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ...)`, depending on the number of parameters. The actual parameters are then passed via the driver.

Not only does this work in all cases (except when `inputs` is empty, depending on your sql-engine `WHERE ... IN ()` may be a syntax error), there is zero chance this will ever expand to an injection attack vector.

Comment: Are you **certain** the number of parameters passed is the same as the number of parameters ("`?`")?